# Quasi-isometry of giant components in Erdos-Renyi graphs

Tags: random-graphs

Take two independent random graphs $G_1, G_2$ in the $G(n,p)$ model for $p = \frac{c}{n}$, $c > 1$ (the question probably makes sense also for $c=1$). Each of them will have a unique giant component, say $C_1$ and $C_2$. Are those giant components quasi-isometric with high probability (with a quasi-isometry constant independent of $n$)?

By quasi-isometry I mean that there exists a map $f: C_1 \to C_2$ (and a similar map in the other direction) such that for all pairs of points $x,y \in C_1$:
$$\frac{1}{C}d_{C_1}(x,y) - L\leq d_{C_2}(f(x), f(y)) \leq C d_{C_1}(x,y) + L$$

where $d_{C_i}$ is the shortest path metric induced on $C_i$ and $C,L$ are constants independent of $n$.